# Checking Credits within MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, function

I need help with confirming how many "credits" a user has on their account within a Mysql Database, with how much an item costs on my website.

I have an item that would cost 30 credits with:

```
<input type="button" onClick="Creds()" value="Buy Now!"/>
```

I need this to them confirm that the logged in user has enough credits in their account,

If not then a redirect to a topup.php page

If the user DOES have enough credits in their account, it would then proceed to the next page and then deduct the credits from their account.

Not sure if its something down the line of this?...

< ?PHP

function Creds(){

$amount=30;

$actual="$row_item1['Credits']";

if($actual < $amount)

```
{header("Location: http://www.mysite/topup.php");}
else 
{header("Location: http://www.mysite/pay.php");}
```

}

?>

This is not working. Any help would be great!

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

May be this might help you . Add this within if statement ....

```
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "alert('Please top up Credits');";
    echo "</script>";
```

Answer (score -1):

You haven't used quotes in alert. Even if my answer may not complete you must replace

```
alert(Please top up Credits);
```

by

```
alert("Please top up Credits");
```

Comment: *Technically correct,*  but it still won't work, because OP is injecting pure JS into PHP without js tags